# contentEquals not working

Tags: android

I am trying to compare two strings.

`s1` - user input (String) and

`s2` - dbHelper.getdata(s1) (String), search if the text in s1 is in the database

**My code works fine BUT I noticed something strange :**

1. Not adding the word/ user input (s1) in listview even if the word is in the database -- (I don't want this one) BUT whenever the word is not in my database it gives a toast which I want. (I use this code).

```js
public void viewWord(View view) {
        s1 = text.getText().toString();
        s2 = dbHelper.getData(s1);
        newData = text.getText().toString();
        s1.trim();
        s2.trim();

        if (s1.isEmpty()) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tap tiles to form a word.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //check if s1 == s2 
        if (s1.contentEquals(s2)) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Word Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (!myList.contains(newData)) { // No duplicate entry

              //display score
              calculate();
              adapter = (ArrayAdapter) wordList.getAdapter();
              adapter.add((String) newData);
              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        } else {

              //check if s1 is not equal to s2
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Word not found. Try a new one.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
```

**2. Adding the word when i use the code below, which I want BUT closing the app when the word is not in the database.**

```js
public void viewWord(View view) {
    s1 = text.getText().toString();
    s2 = dbHelper.getData(s1);
    newData = text.getText().toString();
    s1.trim();
    s2.trim();

    if (s1.isEmpty()) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tap tiles to form a word.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

        //check if s1 is not equal to s2 

        if (!s1.contentEquals(s2)) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Word Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          if (!myList.contains(newData)) { // No duplicate entry
            //display score
            calculate();
          adapter = (ArrayAdapter) wordList.getAdapter();
          adapter.add((String) newData);
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

          }
         } else {

              //check if s1 equal to s2

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Word not found. Try a new one.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

**I WANT IT THIS WAY:** 
If the user input (s1) is in the database (s2) then add user input to `Listview`. Its like:

```
if(s1==s2){ //add user input to listview)}
```

If the user input (s1) is NOT in the database then simply show toast, NOT closing the app like what I am into right now. its like:

```
if(s1!=s2){ //show toast )}
```

**DBHelper**

```js
public String getData(String word)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns={DBHelper.WORD, DBHelper.SCORE};
        Cursor cursor=db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, DBHelper.WORD+ "= '"+word+"'", null, null, null, null);
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            int index1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.WORD);
            int index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.SCORE);
            String words = cursor.getString(index1);
            String score = cursor.getString(index2);
            buffer.append(score +"\n");
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
```

I am using Android Studio and I have no idea about this so I am asking. I've done .contains, .equal but the result is still the same. Badly need help.

Comment: You need to perform equals, not the contentEquals method, you don't have CharSequence here, just plain strings

Comment: I already tried it as noted below but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapter is not responsible for your data, it is responsible for mapping data to ui elements. So you need to put your data to DB and that would change your Cursor automatically, than you will get your list updated. Use CursorAdapter or ContentObserver + ArrayAdpter to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Oh. Can you please my codes for my adapter? I am not really familiar with CursorAdapter or the ContentObserver. I edited the question above.

Comment: I gave you keywords, there are tons of examples in internet, so: Create CursorAdapter, example - https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter. After that insert new word in the DB not to adapter in your case dbHelper.insertData(s1);

Answer (score 0):

trim() function returns the trimmed string, so if you have to change the value of s1 and s2 to trimmed values, do this:

```
s1 = s1.trim();
s2 = s2.trim();
```

And now accordingly check the values. ( equals() can be used here, I guess )

Comment: I used trim() because whenever the user put something in my textview it gives white spaces. and I cant find anything in my database

Comment: Could you please indent the code properly and then ask the question that you have. Be a little more clearer in explain your question.